# Hunt for trapezoid area & arithmetic progression sum formula similarities.

Tags: area, arithmetic-progressions

When I was looking into `Arithmetic progression sum formula`, I found out that it is similar to `Trapezoid are formula`.

- **Arithmetic progression sum formula**

$S_n = \frac{(a_1+a_n)n}{2}$

- **Trapezoid area formula**

$A = \frac{(a+b)h}{2}$

I was wondering: is there any connection between them? Maybe a geometric representation which I'm not able to image or is it just a nonrelevant imagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:  Look at this figure and see if you can reason it out:

[image]

Comment: Ah now I see that, this is excellent. Thank you .